# Objeto como parâmetros para API C#

Tags: c#, web-service, api, asp.net-web-api, angular-5

Tenho uma requisição feita no Angular para o C#. Entretanto não sei como receber os dados na Minha API No C#.

```
 getWithFilters(filter: any) {

    let parametros: any = {
        razaoSocial: filter.razaoSocial,
        cnpj: filter.cnpjcpf,
        telefone: filter.telefone
    }

    return this.http
        .get(this.UrlService + '/Clientes', parametros)
        .map((res: any) => res.data)
        .catch((super.serviceError));
}
```

Assim faço a requisição, entretanto no C# Como faço para receber estes parâmetros?

Agradeço desde já.
Lucas.

Comment: Você pode criar uma ViewModel refletindo o seu objeto para que a API faça a serialização/deserialização no C# para receber e responder o objeto para o seu client. Como está a sua API?

Comment: Angelo, consegui o que queria, entretanto deixei de utilizar o GET e passei a enviar via POST. Pois como se sabe no GET não temos como enviar um body. De toda forma, agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Ahh isso era bem importante,  eu não tinha reparado.

Comment: Sim sim, eu acabei esquecendo na hora também. De toda forma, obrigado.

Comment: Seria legal você colocar a sua solução como resposta para que essa pergunta possa ajudar outros usuários no futuro.

Comment: Vou fazer isso... obrigado pela ideia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar o que eu queria. Entretanto deixei de utilizar o GET e passei a enviar via POST. Pois no GET não temos como enviar um body.